# How to have excel wait for a workbook to open

Tags: excel, vba

My application currently navigates to a vendor website, logs in, opens a report, clicks a download button behind an IFrame(which was cancer to get working), and hits the open button on the open/save dialog box.  Now all thats left for this phase of the project is to have excel wait for the new workbook to open, pull the information into a new sheet, and close the other workbook.

The problem is that no matter what I seem to try the new workbook will never open while the macro is running.  If i add a break in the code everything works just fine.  I've tried application.wait, sleep, DoEvents, and even a msgbox.  I'm kinda stumped here.

```
'This clicks the button that initiates the open/save dialog box in IE
iWin.contentDocument.querySelector("a[title=Excel][onclick*=EXCELOPENXML]").Click

'set the name of the windows the program should look for
iStr = "Reports LeaveXpert Application - Internet Explorer"
eStr = "Case Detail.xlsx  [Protected View] - Excel"
'these are declared as longptr
leHwin = 0
cdHwin = 0

'Grabs the windows handle for the IE window
leHwin = FindWindow(vbNullString, iStr)
'Makes sure the IE window is active
i = SetForegroundWindow(leHwin)
'a little bit of delay
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
'Send the key combination for the open button to the open browser
Application.SendKeys "%{O}"


cdHwin = 0
Debug.Print cdHwin

'this should wait for the new spreadsheet to open but instead the application hangs here and the new spreadsheet never opens.
Do While cdHwin = 0

    'various methods of having the program wait that i've tried
    
    'DoEvents
    'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    'Sleep 1000
    
    'this should set the variable to the windows handle of the new sheet once it opens causing the loop to stop
    cdHwin = FindWindow(vbNullString, eStr)
    
    'This just keeps giving me 0 as an output
    Debug.Print cdHwin
Loop

'we never get to this line of code unless I add a break somewhere in the loop, then the sheet opens and I get the windows handle as output.
Debug.Print cdHwin
```

UPDATE:

IT FINALLY WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I'll have to rethink my single button approach to implementation, but that's a pretty small price to pay.  This has been an off and on project for the better part of 2 weeks and has taken me far more time than I anticipated, mostly due to IFrames being absolute cancer (I seriously hate them).  But I've learned a lot getting this first part working.  Now to start on getting the other two relevant data sources integrated into the spreadsheet.  The more I learn about computer programming; the more I realize how little I know about it.

Oh and Mathieu-Guindon is an absolute hero!

UPDATE 2 for posterity.

Nothing to see here.  I thought I had resolved the problem, but as it turns out I just need more sleep.  Relevant quote from comment discussion.

"*I really need to stop staying up till 4 AM reading posts about computer code and trying to work on this thing. I really think that I went to sleep, had a dream about fixing it, woke up and posted about the "fix", and thought it was real.*"

Update 3:  Final Update on this question.  Relevant explanation is in the comments on the following code.

```
'I made 2 changes that seem to have resolved the issue.
Private Sub AppEvents_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
If Left(Wb.Name, 11) = CaseDetailFileName Then
    'This sub that handles the transfer of data from the newly opened workbook to this workbook.
    'It had an internal call to close the newly opened workbook that I forgot about, so I removed it
    ImportCase Wb
    'a duplicate call also existed out here, there were also a few duplicate ".activate"
    'commands inside the import sub and this if statement that I removed
    Wb.Close
    'This sub handles data sorting and analytics
    CaseFAS
End If
'I had tried copying this line from Workbook_Open a few times before and it 
'didn't resolve the issue by itself,
'but I'm reasonably sure it is part of the solution
Set AppEvents = Me.Application
End Sub
```

A peek under the hood of ImportCase for completeness sake.

```
'This sub handles importing the optis workbook when it opens.  It's called by 
'the AppEvents_WorkbookOpen sub declared in ThisWorkbook
Public Sub ImportCase(ByVal book As Workbook)
Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OptisSource")
'This line clears out any old data
srcSht.Cells.Clear
'Sets the newly opened workbook to be the active sheet
book.Sheets("Case Detail").Activate
'Copys the information and sends it to a predefined sheet in this workbook
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=srcSht.Range("A1")
'sets the newly imported information to the active sheet
srcSht.Activate
'This sub clears out ghost data
ClearNulls
End Sub
```

Comment: So you don't download the workbook? If you download it then you could probably use workbooks.open() which will wait for it to open.

Comment: I've looked into downloading it and from what i understand the only way to handle the save file dialog box you need to have the macro call a vba file thats already on the hard drive.  Since i'm not going to be the only end user, rather than deal with setting it up on multiple machines potentially in multiple locations across town (in a major city) or having excel create the file and deal with file management/windows security permissions etc....  just opening the file seemed like the easier choice.

Comment: But when you open the file, if you debug print this workbook.fullname. is it not saved somewhere on the computer? Or you could do as Chris says and end the sub and do OnTime activate a different sub that is the rest of the code. You just need to `set wb = workbooks("Case Detail.xlsx")` (hopefully). Oh.. and about saving. What about the html? Can you read in the html the source of the file? If yes then you can probably download it

Comment: So the vendor website opens up an iframe with prefilled controls (textboxes, radio buttons, etc...) and then dynamically generates the report and presents it in an iframe.  So even if I could access where the report is stored.  There wouldn't be any useful information to download.  But having excel open the workbook from the temp folder might work.

Comment: is there any way to be sure that the temp folder filepath will be exactly the same on every machine?

C:\Users\ [REDACTED] \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\T0JIBT47\Case Detail.xlsx

Comment: If the file name changes with Case Detail (1).xlsx due to multiple saved then you can loop through open workbooks and `if wb.name like "Case Detail*" then`... Yes there is a environment variable with the temp folder. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win027.htm

Comment: Just as a follow up to one of the questions above: you can use Environ() calls to standardise filepaths and the like across multiple user accounts. For example you could use something like: `FileName = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\T0JIBT47\Case Detail.xlsx"` http://codevba.com/office/environ.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if we just let Excel do its thing, and go with the flow of an event-driven / desynchronized paradigm?

The `Excel.Application` class raises a number of events you can handle in any class module, but the `ThisWorkbook` module can do - you declare a `WithEvents` module-level variable:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents AppEvents As Excel.Application
```

And then you initialize it with an `Application` object reference, perhaps on open - if we're in the `ThisWorkbook` module, we're inheriting an `Application` property from the base `Excel.Workbook` class:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents AppEvents As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvents = Me.Application
End Sub
```

Declaring a `WithEvents` variable makes it available in the top-left dropdown, and then we can pick a member to implement with the top-right dropdown:

[image: selecting 'AppEvents' in the top-left dropdown]

One of the events we can handle at the `Application` level, is a rather convenient `WorkbookOpen` event that gives us a `Wb As Workbook` reference to the workbook that was just opened:

```
Private Sub AppEvents_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

End Sub
```

Here you get to intercept *every* workbook that opens during a macro-enabled session, as long as this `AppEvents` reference remains in-scope - that is, until `ThisWorkbook` is closed.

So the `ThisWorkbook` might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const CaseDetailFileName As String = "Case Detail.xlsx"
Private WithEvents AppEvents As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvents = Me.Application
End Sub

Private Sub AppEvents_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Wb.Name = CaseDetailFileName Then
        DoThingWithCaseDetailWorkbook Wb
    End If
End Sub
```

And then `Public Sub DoThingWithCaseDetailWorkbook(ByVal book As Workbook)` could be defined in any standard module and have access to any module state/variable that was set before the `WorkbookOpen` event fired.

Now the fact that the file is being opened in protected mode (from an untrusted location?) might interfere with this, but then there should be a way to get the script to save the file elsewhere if it's a problem.

Comment: Yea, this answer is amazing.........  I'm not sure if it fixes my issue, because I'm still re-reading it trying to understand it.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, Workbook_open executes every time I open the spreadsheet and tells the workbook to look for AppEvents to happen.  Now when a new workbook opens AppEvents_WorkbookOpen will execute and set Wb to whatever the new workbook is, then execute any code in the sub.

This project needs to pull information from 3 different sources, a vendor, our insurance company and our internal database and be useable by anyone at any level of technical competence.  Even the lady who prints e-mail because the outlook search feature is too complicated........  You've given me ideas!

Comment: @RationalRedneck you got this!

Comment: I'm having a slight reliability issue.  When I first open and run the workbook, it pulls the new spreadsheet just fine, but if I try to run the sub to download the report again;  AppEvents_WorkbookOpen will not trigger a second time, until I save, close, then re-open the workbook.

Comment: @RationalRedneck I'm guessing that's Excel protecting you against potentially malicious downloaded content by opening in protected mode. I wouldn't recommend making a temp/downloads folder a *trusted location*, and for obvious security reasons there is no programmatic way to alter these settings with VBA code. Hmm, maybe configuring IE to elevate trust for the vendor website could have an impact here.

Comment: I've already adjusted settings to get around the protected mode issue.  Sheets from that website always open in read only mode and the first time I run the code it pulls the information just fine and closes the new workbook as expected.  If i run the sub again everything operates as normal until AppEvents_WorkbookOpen should trigger.  It just doesn't.  Adding debug printouts in the sub at various points don't give any output even if it's the literal first line of code before any logical operators.  The sub just does not execute.

Comment: I seem to have figured it out. :)

Comment: @RationalRedneck curious, what was it?

Comment: I thought I had.  but now it's doing it again.  When I Posted that update in the OP I could have SWORN I fixed it.  I really need to stop staying up till 4 AM reading posts about computer code and trying to work on this thing.  I really think that I went to sleep, had a dream about fixing it, woke up and posted about the "fix", and thought it was real.

It seems like AppEvents is somehow getting set to the new workbook that gets opened or is somehow being affecting by the closing of it?  After the new Wb closes, excel no longer looks for events.

Comment: No joke.  I just fixed it.  And I'm reasonably sure I'm not dreaming this time.  Reasonably.....  Check the OP for the final update on this part of the project.  With this issue resolved I can move onto the next step, and leave the knowledge here in a complete state for others.